# Unable to use protocol as associatedtype in another protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have a protocol, `Address`, which inherits from another protocol, `Validator`, and `Address` fulfills the `Validator` requirement in the extension.

There is another protocol, `FromRepresentable`, which has an `associatedType` (`ValueWrapper`) requirement which should be `Validator`.

Now if I try to use `Address` as `associatedType`, then it does not compile. It says,

> Inferred type 'Address' (by matching requirement 'valueForDetail') is
>   invalid: does not conform to 'Validator'.

Is this usage illegal? Shouldn't we be able to use `Address` in place of `Validator`, as all `Addresses` are `Validator`.

Below is the piece of code I am trying.

```
enum ValidationResult {
    case Success
    case Failure(String)
}

protocol Validator {
    func validate() -> ValidationResult
}

//Address inherits Validator
protocol Address: Validator {
    var addressLine1: String {get set}
    var city: String {get set}
    var country: String {get set}
}

////Fulfill Validator protocol requirements in extension
extension Address {
    func validate() -> ValidationResult {
        if addressLine1.isEmpty {
            return .Failure("Address can not be empty")
        }
        return .Success
    }
}

protocol FormRepresentable {
    associatedtype ValueWrapper: Validator
    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ValueWrapper) -> String
}


// Shipping Address conforming to Address protocol. 
// It should also implicitly conform to Validator since
// Address inherits from Validator?
struct ShippingAddress: Address {
    var addressLine1 = "CA"
    var city = "HYD"
    var country = "India"
}


// While compiling, it says:
// Inferred type 'Address' (by matching requirement 'valueForDetail') is invalid: does not conform
// to 'Validator'.
// But Address confroms to Validator.
enum AddressFrom: Int, FormRepresentable {
    case Address1
    case City
    case Country

    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: Address) -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Address1:
            return valueWrapper.addressLine1
        case .City:
            return valueWrapper.city
        case .Country:
            return valueWrapper.country
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Filed a [bug.](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1581)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem, which [David has already alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37360351/2976878), is that once you constrain a protocol's `associatedtype` to a specific (non `@objc`) protocol, you have to use a concrete type to satisfy that requirement.

This is because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – therefore meaning that you cannot use `Address` to satisfy the protocol's associated type requirement of a type that conforms to `Validator`, as `Address` is *not* a type that conforms to `Validator`.

As I demonstrate [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878), consider the counter-example of:

```
protocol Validator {
    init()
}
protocol Address : Validator {}

protocol FormRepresentable {
    associatedtype ValueWrapper: Validator
}

extension FormRepresentable {
    static func foo() {
        // if ValueWrapper were allowed to be an Address or Validator,
        // what instance should we be constructing here?
        // we cannot create an instance of a protocol.
        print(ValueWrapper.init())
    }
}

// therefore, we cannot say:
enum AddressFrom : FormRepresentable {
    typealias ValueWrapper = Address
}
```

The simplest solution would be to ditch the `Validator` protocol constraint on your `ValueWrapper` associated type, allowing you to use an abstract type in the method argument.

```
protocol FormRepresentable {
    associatedtype ValueWrapper
    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ValueWrapper) -> String
}
```

```
enum AddressFrom : Int, FormRepresentable {

    // ...

    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: Address) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you need the associated type constraint, and each `AddressFrom` instance only expects a single concrete implementation of `Address` as an input – you could use generics in order for your `AddressFrom` to be initialised with a given concrete type of address to be used in your method.

```
protocol FormRepresentable {
    associatedtype ValueWrapper : Validator
    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ValueWrapper) -> String
}
```

```
enum AddressFrom<T : Address> : Int, FormRepresentable {

    // ...

    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: T) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
// replace ShippingAddress with whatever concrete type you want AddressFrom to use
let addressFrom = AddressFrom<ShippingAddress>.Address1
```

However, if you require both the associated type constraint *and* each `AddressFrom` instance must be able to handle an input of any type of `Address` – you'll have use a type erasure in order to wrap an arbitrary `Address` in a concrete type.

```
protocol FormRepresentable {
    associatedtype ValueWrapper : Validator
    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ValueWrapper) -> String
}
```

```
struct AnyAddress : Address {

    private var _base: Address

    var addressLine1: String {
        get {return _base.addressLine1}
        set {_base.addressLine1 = newValue}
    }
    var country: String {
        get {return _base.country}
        set {_base.country = newValue}
    }
    var city: String {
        get {return _base.city}
        set {_base.city = newValue}
    }

    init(_ base: Address) {
        _base = base
    }
}
```

```
enum AddressFrom : Int, FormRepresentable {

    // ...

    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: AnyAddress) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
let addressFrom = AddressFrom.Address1

let address = ShippingAddress(addressLine1: "", city: "", country: "")

addressFrom.valueForDetail(AnyAddress(address))
```

Comment: Alright, I get it, but is there any reason why we have to use concreteType for an associatedType with a protocol constraint? Compiler does not issue any error if we use Address as an argument for a function which expects Validator.

Comment: I don't get it that why do we have to use concrete type if associatedType has protocol constraint. Does it have something to do with invariance behaviour or memory allocation? Do you have any reference where I can more information on this.

Comment: @VishalSingh I'm afraid I can't offer any better reason than "because that's just the way it is" – I certainly can't think of a reason why it shouldn't be possible, seeing as the unconstrained version works fine. I also can't seem to find anything on the swift evolution mailing list or bug tracker about this. It might well be worth filing a [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) on, and seeing what they say about it.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that, and will update this post if I get anything. Till then, I will remember this as a rule :)

Comment: Happy to help, I'll certainly be interested in the response :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a several issues:

First of all, you don't actually declare that Address implements Validator

```
//Address inherits Validator
protocol Address : Validator {
    var addressLine1: String {get set}
    var city: String {get set}
    var country: String {get set}
}
```

And you don't declare the associated type for ValueWrapper:

```
typealias ValueWrapper = ShippingAddress
```

And you seem to actually be wanting AddressFrom.valueForDetail to take a `ShippingAddress`:

```
func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ShippingAddress) -> String {
    switch self {
    case .Address1:
        return valueWrapper.addressLine1
    case .City:
        return valueWrapper.city
    case .Country:
        return valueWrapper.country
    }
}
```

Altogether, it looks like:

```
enum ValidationResult {
    case Success
    case Failure(String)
}

protocol Validator {
    func validate() -> ValidationResult
}

//Address inherits Validator
protocol Address : Validator {
    var addressLine1: String {get set}
    var city: String {get set}
    var country: String {get set}
}

////Fulfill Validator protocol requirements in extension
extension Address {
    func validate() -> ValidationResult {
        if addressLine1.isEmpty {
            return .Failure("Address can not be empty")
        }
        return .Success
    }
}

protocol FormRepresentable {
    associatedtype ValueWrapper: Validator
    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ValueWrapper) -> String
}


// Shipping Address conforming to Address protocol.
// It should also implicity conform to Validator since
// Address inherits from Validator?
struct ShippingAddress: Address {
    var addressLine1 = "CA"
    var city = "HYD"
    var country = "India"
}


// While compiling, it says:
// Inferred type 'Address' (by matching requirement 'valueForDetail') is invalid: does not conform
// to 'Validator'.
// But Address confroms to Validator.
enum AddressFrom: Int, FormRepresentable {
    case Address1
    case City
    case Country

    // define associated type for FormRepresentable
    typealias ValueWrapper = ShippingAddress
    func valueForDetail(valueWrapper: ShippingAddress) -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Address1:
            return valueWrapper.addressLine1
        case .City:
            return valueWrapper.city
        case .Country:
            return valueWrapper.country
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry I posted this question while I was still trying to get it working. I edited the code snippet. Address actually inherits from  Validator. Regarding typealias, I think it should be able to infer ValueWrapper from valueForDetail(_: Address) function. I do not want it to be concretetype.

Comment: Note that you don't actually have to explicitly define the protocol's `associatedtype` (through the `typealias`) in your implementation, Swift can infer it from the method argument type.