# Generic variables in protocols with associated types. Bug?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift2, associated-types

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.3. I have difficulties using protocols with associated types that have variables. Look at the example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}
class SomeProtocolImpl: SomeProtocol {}

protocol ProtocolWithAssociatedType {
    associatedtype T: SomeProtocol

    var variable: T { get }
}

class TestClass: ProtocolWithAssociatedType {

    var variable: SomeProtocol = SomeProtocolImpl()

}
```

For some reason, compiler shows errors:
[image: error image]
How is that possible? Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug? A known one?

What I've tried:

defined typealias for that associated type:

```
class TestClass: ProtocolWithAssociatedType {
    typealias O = SomeProtocol
    var variable: SomeProtocol = SomeProtocolImpl()
}
```

nope.

Used method instead:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}
class SomeProtocolImpl: SomeProtocol {}

protocol ProtocolWithAssociatedType {
    associatedtype T: SomeProtocol

    func someMethod() -> T
}

class TestClass: ProtocolWithAssociatedType {
    typealias T = SomeProtocol

    func someMethod() -> SomeProtocol {
        return SomeProtocolImpl()
    }

}
```

just got different errors:
[image: second error image]

How should I create protocol with associated type and variable and avoid this errors?

Comment: @Hamish yeah, indeed, you're right

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs a specific type for `T` that conforms to `SomeProtocol`.

While this line looks correct

```
var variable: SomeProtocol
```

the problem the compiler is running into is that `SomeProtocol` is not a type, it's a protocol.

The easiest solution, tell the compiler a type to use

```
var variable: SomeProtocolImpl = SomeProtocolImpl()
```

or just let it figure it out itself.

```
var variable = SomeProtocolImpl()
```

Comment: Your explanation is right, but I still can't understand why `The compiler needs a specific type for T that conforms to SomeProtocol`. Is there any reason for it? Is it just a temporarily compile limitation?

Comment: And unfortunately your answer doesn't solve my problem - I still need to declare this variable as a protocol to preserve incapsulation and avoid relying on concrete implementation.

Comment: Then you'd have to change your protocol to not use an associated type. `var variable: SomeProtocol { get }`

Comment: solution with type erasure wrappers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360114/unable-to-use-protocol-as-associatedtype-in-another-protocol-in-swift seems much more appropriate