# Swift associatedType from protocol type - how to do that?

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types

I'm having issues using associated type as protocol:

```
protocol Searchable{    
    func matches(text: String) -> Bool
}

protocol ArticleProtocol: Searchable {
    var title: String {get set}
}

extension ArticleProtocol {
    func matches(text: String) -> Bool {
        return title.containsString(text)
    }
}

struct FirstArticle: ArticleProtocol {
      var title: String = ""
}

struct SecondArticle: ArticleProtocol {
      var title: String = ""
}

protocol SearchResultsProtocol: class {    
    associatedtype T: Searchable
}
```

When I try to implement search results protocol, I get compile issue:

"type SearchArticles does not conform to protocol SearchResultsProtocol"

```
class SearchArticles: SearchResultsProtocol {
   typealias T = ArticleProtocol
}
```

As I understand, it happens because T in SearchArticles class is not from concrete type (struct in that example), but from protocol type.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use protocol as associatedtype in another protocol in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360114/unable-to-use-protocol-as-associatedtype-in-another-protocol-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

An `associatedtype` is not meant to be a placeholder (protocol), it is meant to be a concrete type.  By adding a generic to the class declaration you can achieve the same result you want like this....

```
class SearchArticles<V: ArticleProtocol>: SearchResultsProtocol {
    typealias T = V
}
```

Then, as you use `SearchArticles` around your app, you can declare `let foo = SearchArticles<FirstArticle>` or `let foo = SearchArticles<SecondArticle>`