# Non-generic protocol used as concrete type does not conform to himself

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I got to this weird compiler limitation in Swift 3.1, tested in a playground. Any solution?

[image]

Seems like a compiler bug, suggestions?
Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, [protocols do not conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/2976878) – you cannot use `Protocol1` as a type that conforms to `Protocol1`. This isn't a bug, it's by design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes non sense right? This is such a nonesense limitation..

Comment: It does make sense. Consider if you had a `static` protocol requirement on `Protocol1` – if I had a `func foo<T : Protocol1>(_: T.Type) {}`, I can access static protocol requirements on `T`. You cannot access static requirements on a protocol type, only on concrete types – therefore allowing protocols to conform to themselves is unsound. I do however agree that the workaround (type erasers) is quite mundane – hopefully in a future version of the language, Swift will support *some* language feature to alleviate this burden.

Comment: @Hamish I do not really see the point in what you said about a static protocol requirement, I tested your proposal and the result is here: http://imgur.com/iFbZA0m

Comment: I was talking about calling the static requirements on `T`, not `param` (which is an existential metatype in your example, so works fine). To be fair, it wasn't the best example – I have illustrated a (hopefully) better one in [my answer to the linked Q&A here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) :)

Comment: Oh wow, totally forgot that I've already answered basically this exact question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37360114/2976878) – will go ahead and close as a dupe of both :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, protocols used as concrete types may not conform to themselves. This is explained by Hamish [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193), and also [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3038) there is a JIRA resolved bug report about it from the Swift project. Both links contain code to allow you understand the issue.