# Why won't this generic protocol-based framework compile?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Below is a SSCCE of a Swift 4 framework I'm working on in Xcode 9 Beta 5:

```swift
// MARK: - Protocols

public protocol BaseFoo {
    associatedtype FooBar: Bar
}



public protocol Bar {
    associatedtype BarData: DataHolder
}
public extension Bar {
    public typealias Callback = BarCallback<BarData>
}



public typealias BarCallback<Result: DataHolder> = (Result?, Error?) -> Void



public protocol DataHolder {
}



// MARK: - Implementations

public class MyFoo: BaseFoo { // Does not compile
    public typealias FooBar = MyBar
}



public protocol MyBar: Bar where BarData: MyDataHolder {
}
public protocol MyDataHolder: DataHolder {
}
```

But the compiler complains that "`Type 'MyFoo' does not conform to protocol 'BaseFoo'`". Xcode asks "Do you want to add protocol stubs?" and when I click "Fix", it does this:

```
public class MyFoo: BaseFoo {
    public typealias FooBar = <#type#>

    public typealias FooBar = MyBar
}
```

That seems to indicate that `MyBar` is not the proper type to satisfy `FooBar`, but it's clearly a `DataHolder`, just as required. **What's going on here, and how do I fix it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use protocol as associatedtype in another protocol in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360114/unable-to-use-protocol-as-associatedtype-in-another-protocol-in-swift)

Comment: It is indeed as you suspect; `MyBar` is not a type that conforms to `Bar`.

Comment: @Hamish close, but compiling with Swift 3 revealed there was one crucially missing piece of information.

Comment: @Hamish why do you think `MyBar` is not a `Bar`? Its declaration clearly inherits.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that `Bar` had an associated type, my bad. `MyBar` is not a type that conforms to `Bar` because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

Comment: @Hamish Now I'm even more confused. Why do you think `MyBar` conforms to `MyBar`?

Comment: I don't – `MyBar` *doesn't* conform to `MyBar`, because it's a protocol and protocols don't conform to themselves :)

Comment: @Hamish I see. I'd love if you elaborated more on this in an answer, because even though I found a solution to my problem, I'm not sure I know the root cause.

Comment: I (think at least) I've already given a detailed answer to this both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37360490/2976878) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878). Is there anything in specific you need clarifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some light was shed on this when I tried to compile using Swift 3, which only required minimal changes. Now, I get two errors:

```swift
public class MyFoo: BaseFoo { // Type 'MyFoo' does not conform to protocol 'BaseFoo'
    public typealias FooBar = MyBar // Protocol 'MyBar' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
}
```

Aha! Now this is an error I'm used to dealing with. So, I put it in the class declaration as a generic parameter:

```
public class MyFoo<_MyBar: MyBar>: BaseFoo {
    public typealias FooBar = _MyBar
}
```

And now it compiles just fine! Bringing that fix back into Swift 4 gives the same result; now it compiles just fine.

So the problem was that **`MyBar` was too generic to be used directly as a type, and needs to be abstracted through a generic parameter.**