# Conforming to protocol with associatedtype

Tags: swift

I stuck with Swift syntax. This code example won't compile and i can't find why. It says

> Type 'TextMessageViewModelDefaultBuilder' does not conform to protocol
>   'ViewModelBuilderProtocol'

```
import Foundation

protocol MessageModelProtocol { }
protocol MessageViewModelProtocol { }

protocol TextMessageViewModelProtocol:MessageViewModelProtocol {}
protocol TextMessageModelProtocol:MessageModelProtocol {}

protocol ViewModelBuilderProtocol {
    associatedtype ModelT: MessageModelProtocol
    associatedtype ViewModelT: MessageViewModelProtocol
    func canCreateViewModel(fromModel model: Any) -> Bool
    func createViewModel(_ model: ModelT) -> ViewModelT
}

class TextMessageViewModelDefaultBuilder: ViewModelBuilderProtocol {
    typealias ModelT = TextMessageModelProtocol
    typealias ViewModelT = TextMessageViewModelProtocol

    init() {}

    func createViewModel(_ textMessage: ModelT) -> ViewModelT {
        return ViewModelT()
    }

    func canCreateViewModel(fromModel model: Any) -> Bool {
        return model is ModelT
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare [Unable to use protocol as associatedtype in another protocol in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37360114/2976878) & [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/2976878)

Comment: Hmm so the reason is i can't use `protocol` types to implement requirement of `associatedtype`? Only concrete type?

Comment: You cannot currently satisfy a placeholder type that's constrained to some protocol with a (non-`@objc`) protocol type, as such protocols do not conform to themselves (the reason why this is the case is explained in the above Q&As I linked to). Specifically in your example, `TextMessageModelProtocol` is not a type that conforms to `MessageModelProtocol`, despite deriving from it.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate into this. On first look it's very weird restriction.

Answer (score -1):

**Hamish** in comments pointed to that fact that in Swift protocols doesn't conforms to themselves. Thus i can't use protocol types to implement requirement of associatedtype.